# How to make a line below text without text-decoration: underline?

Tags: html, css

I need to add a line below the text, without **text-decoration: underline;** 
otherwise how to make a custom space between text and line.

### What we do

Comment: try border bottom  :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `Border-Bottom` with some `Padding-Bottom`.

```css
a {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<a>Example Text</a>
```

Also you can use **pseudo element**, use after or before to add a line under the text or anything else.

```css
a::after {
 display: block;
   content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a {
position: relative;  
}
```

```html
<a>Example Text</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

**border-bottom**:

```css
span{
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<span>What we do</span>
```